# Calling a method from a different view controller in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

Is there any way to call a method created in one of my view controllers in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in delegate.m?

Specifically, I would like to call the following, a method from one of my 3 views:

This is the original method from myViewController.m

```
- (void)setInitialState
{
    self.start.enabled = YES;
    self.stop.enabled = NO;
    self.calculate.enabled = NO;
    self.resume.enabled = NO;
}
```

Calling this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` would make everything look that way I would like on initial launch after installation.

I have tried importing `myViewController.h` into `delegate.m`, but I am not sure how I should phrase the code so that it will know to run `setInitialState` on `myViewController` from `delegate`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you should put call to setInitialState method inside your ViewController's init method and not expose it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Just create this viewController and that's it

Comment: Giving that a shot now. Thanks for the response. This did not work, as in I am not seeing the initialization: `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    
    // this will set initial state for initial launch
        [self.setInitialState];
    }
    return self;`

Comment: try -(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder method of your viewcontroller.

Comment: @pawan I have a whole set of encoder/decoder code for maintaining my user input data during background/terminate/restart. I am not sure how I would implement it in the initWithCoder method. It seems like overkill, unless I am misunderstanding. Is it not possible or not recommended to just call the method like I asked?

Comment: you are using storyboard , or xib ?

Comment: @pawan storyboard in Xcode 5.

Comment: in that case you should call 'setInitialState' from viewDidLoad method.

Comment: @pawan I have it there already, but I am using NSUserDefaults to keep a few text views and button states persistent when going back and forth to my main menu via navigation controller back arrow. I have tried setting initial values for the NSUserDefaults using a Plist, which gives the desired effect, but which also kills my state restoration on background/terminate/restart using NSCoder/Decoder. I am trying to set the initial state of the buttons, etc. JUST for the very firsts initial launch after installation. All of the other functionality of the app works perfectly.

Comment: oh, i misunderstood the question. with restoration, only global variable (ex-nsuserdefault) can help you. you should always store the state of button whenever its state is changing & syns nsuserdefault.  init method ,its never get called, because the viewcontrollers are already initialized in navigation stack.

Comment: @pawan I am confused then. So is there no way of setting my initial NSUserDefaults while still being able to implement state restoration using encode/decode? That can't be.

Comment: if you change the value & sync nsuserdefault. there is no way we can get it back again.

Comment: @pawan so do I get rid of the sync call? I am sorry I am rather new to this and am just looking for a solution that allow me to keep both types of state restoration, i.e. view controller to menu to view controller and background/terminate/restart.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47543/discussion-between-pawan-and-c-dub)

Answer (score 0):

you can create the object of myViewController class and call the setInitialState() method like

```
myViewController *objMyVC = [[myViewController alloc]init];
```

or you can also use

```
myViewController *objMyVC = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourNibName" bundle:nil]];

[objMyVC setInitialState];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just tried this: `UIViewController *TankCalculatorViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TankCalculatorViewController" bundle:nil];
    
    [TankCalculatorViewController setInitialState];` Xcode wanted to change myViewController to UIViewController. I am getting the following error in code. `/Users/pesky_human/Desktop/xcode_projects/CNW_Apps/Trak_Strategies_LLC/FlowTrak/FlowTrak/TrakAppDelegate.m:23:35: No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'setInitialState'`

Comment: i think you does not get reference to view in nib file.

Comment: How do I find the name of the nib file? I am looking through all of my files and don't see it.

Comment: I'm using storyboards, BTW.